# Node.js repeat database request in .then chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request, repeat

I use a promise `.then` chain. In this chain I calculate some bounds, build the sql statement and send a request to the database. If the database request gives no result, I want to change something by calculating the bounds and do the same steps again. I want to repeat this until there is a database result.

This is my code:

```
.then(function(){
    return calcBound.calcBounds(req.body,0);
  })
  .then(function(options){
    return sqlStatementBuilder.sqlStatementBuilder(options);
  })
  .then(function(statement){
    return db_request.db_request(statement);
  })
  .then(function(dbResult){
    if(dbResult.length <= 0){ // if there are no results from the database
      console.log("There are no results for this filter options");
      var newDBResult;
      do{
        newDBResult = calcBound.calcBounds(req.body, addToOffset)              
                .then(function(options){
                  return sqlStatementBuilder.sqlStatementBuilder(options);
                })
                .then(function(statement){
                  return db_request.db_request(statement);
                })
      } while(dbResult.length <= 0);
      return newDBResult.sort(sortArray.compareRecordId);
    }else{
      return dbResult.sort(sortArray.compareRecordId);
    }
  })
```

The while loop is not a good idea her this will end up as "heap out of memory".

What would be a better solution to do this?

Comment: If not a while loop then you need a `max_tries` ... otherwise why is your function in a while loop causing a heap out of memory? Something else might be going wrong...

Comment: call a function recursively. It will be the sanest thing to do

Comment: Calling a recursive function with `addToOffset` as variable parameter would look as a solution in this scenario.

Comment: in your loop, you call your calcBounds() repeatedly without waiting for the promises to resolve (or setting dbResult), so you have an endless loop here. You need to invoke your promise chain again, recursive and introduce a "addToOffset" parameter if no result was found - and a reasonable abort condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function `dummyRecursiveFunction` with `addToOffset` as a parameter and call it until you get results in `dbResult`

```
function dummyRecursiveFunction(addToOffset) {
  someFunction()
  .then(function(){
    return calcBound.calcBounds(req.body, addToOffset);
  })
  .then(function(options){
    return sqlStatementBuilder.sqlStatementBuilder(options);
  })
  .then(function(statement){
    return db_request.db_request(statement);
  })
  .then(function(dbResult) {
    if(dbResult.length > 0) {
      return dbResult.sort(sortArray.compareRecordId);
    } else {
      // newOffset: Your recalculated offset value.
      dummyRecursiveFunction(newOffset);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: is there a possiblity to set `max_tries`?

Comment: Of course, you can take a variable let us say `var max_tries = 1000;` and add a parameter `numberOfTries` to your function `dummyRecursiveFunction(numberOfTries, addToOffset)`. Increment the value of `numberOfTries` each time you call it. Also, put a check `numberOfTries < max_tries` before running your function.